# Unable to install TestNG plugin in eclips.. unable to connect MVN Repository

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng-eclipse

i tried **installing TestNg** plugin from Eclips marketplace..

while that- after pressing **confirm** button on (confirm selected features) tab as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFTXB.png)
then after pressed **Finish**

ahead it is showing error like follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jepWI.png)

it is saying **unable to connect MVN Repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVdNK.png)

i have updated my eclips to latest version.
still showing error while installation..

what could be the problem.. help me in resolving this.

i didn't found any solution from old references/ answers..

Comment: The error is about an Eclipse update site, not a MVN repository. This might be a temporary outage of https://testng.org, especially since previous pages were successfully loaded before the connection to https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/6.12.0/compositeContent.xml failed. Can you open this web site in a web browser? Are you behind something that limits internet traffic?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to reply.    later that problem resolved Thanks.

Comment: Glad to see that the problem disappeared. You could give a self-answer or delete your question.